# Get the previous value before updating a field: JPA/SpringBoot/Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a Kotlin SpringBoot application and for a specific field I do the following:

```
  @Transactional
  @Modifying
  @Query(nativeQuery = true, value =
  """
      UPDATE someTable SET someField = ?1 WHERE id = ?2

    """)
  fun updateBySomeFieldAndId(someField: Int?, id: UUID?): Int
```

I am trying to grab the value for such field before it gets updated. Please note that the update only occurs once (as per some other logic), so I will always have one and only one original value and one and one updated one. Can you help? I was looking at Hibernate Envers, but is there a simpler approach to it?

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to do with the old value? Do you want to log it /insert it into another log table?

Comment: I would like to log it, rather than persisting into a log table. I have an event tracking approach that is keeping track of the change, but not of the original value

Comment: How About a trigger? Any update on the table will put the old value in another table.